# How to fix Philips Hue API v2 404 Not Found Error

Tags: philips-hue

Today, I wanted to try out the Philips Hue v2 CLIP API. I managed to fetch the credentials, but am stuck when I try to fetch the devices, as I'm getting a 404 Error.

Here is a Screenshot of the CLIP API Debugger:
[image: Screenshot CLIP API Debugger]

And here is one of my browser:
[image: Browser Screenshot]